# Is there a way to know if a 0 is in between 2 other integers, in a list or string?

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to create a program that counts the amount of significant figures in a number. I am stuck on trying to create a block of code that detects whether a 0 is in between 2 other integers, must be > 1 but < 9.

I am new to coding, so sorry if there is something blatantly obvious, but I have tried getting the count of any number and putting that in a parameter, and I am having no luck. I was able to get the program to count the significant figures if the number is similar to 12300000, then there would only be 3 significant figures.

```
num = list(input('What is your number: '))
num_len = len(num)
any = ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9']

for random in range(1,10):
    any_list = list(str(random))

if '0' in num:
    new_len = num_len - num.count('0')
    new_len1 = new_len + num.count('0') + 1

    if '0' in num[1:]:
        print('true')

    if '0' in num[new_len:new_len1]:
        print(len(num) - num.count('0'))
else:
    print(len(num))
```

If a zero is in between 2 numbers, like 101, it should count 3 significant zeroes. If a 0 is in between 2 numbers then the next 0 isn't, like 1010, it should only 3 significant figures(the 101).

Comment: Have you tried using strip, `test = "001020000"` `print(test.strip("0")) -> "102"` `print(len(test.strip("0"))) -> 3`

Answer (score 0):

Turn the problem around. Instead of trying to detect the zeroes in the middle that you want to include, get rid of the zeroes on the outside that you want to *exclude*. There's already a built-in function for that: [`str.strip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip).

```
significant = len(num.strip('0'))
```